# add title to collection of pandas hist plots

Tags: python, pandas, title, histogram

I'm looking for advice on how to show a title at the top of a collection of histogram plots that have been generated by a pandas df.hist() command. For instance, in the histogram figure block generated by the code below I'd like to place a general title (e.g. 'My collection of histogram plots') at the top of the figure:

```
data = DataFrame(np.random.randn(500).reshape(100,5), columns=list('abcde'))
axes = data.hist(sharey=True, sharex=True)
```

I've tried using the *title* keyword in the hist command (i.e. title='My collection of histogram plots'), but that didn't work.

The following code *does* work (in an ipython notebook) by adding text to one of the axes, but is a bit of a kludge.

```
axes[0,1].text(0.5, 1.4,'My collection of histogram plots', horizontalalignment='center',
               verticalalignment='center', transform=axes[0,1].transAxes)
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can use `suptitle()`:

```
import pylab as pl
from pandas import *
data = DataFrame(np.random.randn(500).reshape(100,5), columns=list('abcde'))
axes = data.hist(sharey=True, sharex=True)
pl.suptitle("This is Figure title")
```

Comment: Is there any technical reason why `hist()` can't have a named `title` argument?

Answer (score 116):

With newer Pandas versions, if someone is interested, here a slightly different solution with Pandas only:

```
ax = data.plot(kind='hist',subplots=True,sharex=True,sharey=True,title='My title')
```

Answer (score 25):

I found a better way:

```
plt.subplot(2,3,1)  # if use subplot
df = pd.read_csv('documents',low_memory=False)
df['column'].hist()
plt.title('your title')
```

It is very easy, display well at the top, and will not mess up your subplot.

Answer (score 17):

for `matplotlib.pyplot`, you can use:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# ...
plt.suptitle("your title")
```

or if you're using a `Figure` object directly,

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, axs = plt.subplots(...)
# ...
fig.suptitle("your title")
```

See [this example](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/figure_title.html).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to quickly loop through all columns and get hist plots with titles, try this one.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, axs = plt.subplots(len(data.columns), figsize=(4,10))
for n, col in enumerate(data.columns):
    data[col].hist(ax=axs[n],legend=True)
```